# P5 component stopped updating in mobile browser (but works in pc browser)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, p5.js, tensorflow.js

I have this app that grabs your webcam's video stream and classifies the objects in the picture. You can see the deployed version here: 
[ndf-react.firebaseapp.com](http://ndf-react.firebaseapp.com)

The app works okay with a pc web browser (in my case, Chrome), but it encountered a few problems when I'm trying to view in a mobile browser.

Safari on iPhone was able to get the basic UI showing. However, the label (blue text in the video screen) does not update, this is a continuously updated value, which shows the predicted label of the video stream.

The value updates just fine in a pc browser.

I'm definitely unsure of why this would happen. Any help appreciated.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/kyujyokei/ndf-react

Comment: Can you please narrow the problem down to a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Hi! Thanks for the tip. I've tried to narrow down and re-phrase the question to be more clear. Hope that helps. Please let me know if it still looks confusing to you.